# Using Selenium with Python to get INFO level browser console log events on Edge

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm, microsoft-edge, desiredcapabilities

I'm trying to get INFO level browser console log events from Edge using Python/Selenium on PyCharm but current configuration only returns WARNING level logs from browser. I'm using msedge.selenium_tools library intentionally because webdriver library on Edge seems to be deprecated.

```
import time
from msedge.selenium_tools import EdgeOptions
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.EDGE
capabilities['loggingPrefs'] = {'browser': 'ALL'}
capabilities['acceptInsecureCerts'] = bool(True)

edge_options = EdgeOptions()
edge_options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
edge_options.use_chromium = True
driver = Edge(options=edge_options, desired_capabilities=capabilities, executable_path=r"C:\\Users\\myuser\\Documents\\edgedriver_win64\\msedgedriver.exe")

     ...
```

Output:

```
[{'level': 'WARNING', 'message': 'Message I'm getting'}]
```

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Comment: Hello Peng, I wrote a comment to your post 2 hours after you posted it, I think you missed it :). Since I'm a new user, SO doesn't allow me to upvote you, very sorry. Yesterday, I even managed to get INFO events from an Android phone via Appium. So everything works great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, I tested it with webdriver in Selenium 4.1.0 and found that your requirement can be achieved. And you must to use **ms:loggingPrefs** instead of `loggingPrefs`.

Simple code(work in Edge version 97.0.1072.62):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

d = DesiredCapabilities.EDGE
d['ms:loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL' }

driver = webdriver.Edge(capabilities=d,executable_path = r"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\msedgedriver.exe")
driver.get('<your website url>')

entry = driver.get_log("browser")
print(entry)
```

##### Edit:

After some testing, I found that using the `msedge.selenium_tools` library also requires a similar modification to the corresponding code to make it work based on [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/capabilities-edge-options#edgeoptions-object), but I didn't find the corresponding documentation(maybe I missed).

Code sample below:

```
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge, EdgeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

# enable browser logging
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.EDGE
capabilities['ms:loggingPrefs'] = {'browser': 'ALL'}
capabilities['acceptInsecureCerts'] = bool(True)

# load the desired webpage
edge_options = EdgeOptions()
edge_options.use_chromium = True
edge_options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
edge_options.set_capability("ms:edgeOptions",capabilities)

driver = Edge(options = edge_options, executable_path=r"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\msedgedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://localhost:44356/Index.html')

# print messages
entry = driver.get_log("browser")
print(entry)
```

Result like this:

[image]

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Works like magic, thank you. I was using goog:loggingPrefs for Chrome but couldn't find any documentation regarding what should I be using for Edge.

Comment: Hi @davegurney, I've edited my answer and I think this will work for you as well.

Comment: This is very useful. Anyone know what is the prefix for Firefox, Opera, Safari,?? in the loggingPrefs.  @XudongPeng ??